# Sort List elements in Elixir Lang

Tags: elixir

I have a list of strings that I want to order in two ways.

1. Alphabetically
2. By string length

Comment: What do you mean by without looping? The sorting operation needs to traverse through the list. In any case, maybe Enum.sort/2 is what you are looking for?

Comment: @JoséValim You're right. I edited the question so it doesn't mislead. The Enum module has all I need. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To sort a list of strings alphabetically, you can just use [`Enum.sort/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/1), which will order items by their default order (which is alphabetic ordering for strings).

```
iex> Enum.sort(["b", "aaa", "cc"])
["aaa", "b", "cc"]
```

To sort a list by a different property, such as string length, you can use [`Enum.sort_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort_by/3), which takes a mapper function as second argument. The values will then be sorted by the result of this function applied to each element.

```
iex> Enum.sort_by(["b", "aaa", "cc"], &String.length/1)
["b", "cc", "aaa"]
```